# Popup browser incompability

Tags: jquery, browser, popup, google-chrome

I have a popup with drop down menus on it. I've scaled it down and simplified it for test purposes, but it still doesn't work the way I want/it should.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
    jQuery('.trigger').click(function(){
      var picker = jQuery('.popup');
      jQuery('<div></div>').css({
        height: screen.height, 
        width: screen.width, 
        position: 'absolute',
        'z-index': -1,
        top: picker.offset().top*-1, 
        left: picker.offset().left*-1,
        border: '1px solid red'
      }).click(function(){
         picker.trigger('focusout');
         jQuery(this).hide();
      }).prependTo(picker); 
      picker.css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
    jQuery('.popup').live("focusout", function() {
      jQuery('.popup').fadeTo(500, 0.0, function() {
        jQuery('.popup').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        jQuery('.popup').css('opacity', '1.0');
      });
    });
  });  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <input type=text class=trigger />
    <div id=popup-div class=popup style="visibility: hidden; border: 1px solid red">        
        <select>
        <option>option1</option>
        </select>
        <p>Popup text</p>       
    </div>
  </p>
</body>
```

When you click on the input field, a 'popup' appears, if you click outside the red border it fades away. If you click on the select option it shouldn't dissappear! However on this point, Chrome doesn't work the same as IE/FF/Opera/Safari, and makes the div dissappear.

(Using Chrome 4.0.295.0)

Does anybody knows a work-around for Chrome? 
Calling event.stopPropagation() on select elements did not work so far

Answer (score 0):

This seems to behave correctly in **Chrome 5.0.375.23**, however I'd change this up a bit to have consistent behavior in all browsers including Chrome 4, since `focusout` isn't necessarily a valid event on an element that can't have `focus` in the first place.  A better approach here is to take advantage of bubbling and event order.  To do this, you'd replace this:

```
jQuery('.popup').live("focusout", function() {
  jQuery('.popup').fadeTo(500, 0.0, function() {
    jQuery('.popup').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    jQuery('.popup').css('opacity', '1.0');
  });
});
```

With this:

```
jQuery('.popup, .trigger').live('click', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
});
jQuery(document).click(function() {
  jQuery('.popup:visible').fadeTo(500, 0.0, function() {
    jQuery(this).css('visibility', 'hidden').css('opacity', '1.0');
  });
});
```

What this does is if the `click` originated inside a popup element or a trigger (opening it), the hide action isn't executed, because the execution of handlers of this event on the same element (`document`) is prevented (as is the bubble, but that doesn't matter in the above code).  Even though [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) lives on the document, with [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) you can prevent handlers at the same level from executing if they were bound later, since handlers are executed in the order they were bound.

As an aside on `.stopPropgation()`: 
If you change this to just [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), the other handler still executes, hiding the popup (though you could use [`event.stopProgation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and check [`event.isPropogationStopped()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.isPropagationStopped/) in the second handler).